# How to update react state without re-rendering component?

Tags: reactjs

I am building a gallery app where I need to create multiple HTTP requests to pull gallery entries(images & videos).

As gallery will be auto scrolling entries, I am trying to prevent re-rendering component when I make subsequent HTTP requests and update the state.

Thanks

Comment: If there was a way to do this, it wouldn't be advised.

Comment: What? You can do this, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: by implementing a `shouldComponentUpdate` function

Comment: You should not be worried to re-render multiple times, React intelligently re-renders only components which props were changed. You should always have your state and dom in sync. That's the base concept of React.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's an example of only re-rendering when a particular condition is fulfilled (e.g. finished fetching).

For example, here we only re-render if the value reaches 3.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component { 
  state = { 
    value: 0, 
  }

  add = () => {
    this.setState({ value: this.state.value + 1});
  } 

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) { 
    if (nextState.value !== 3) { 
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  render() { 
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <p>Value is: {this.state.value}</p>
        <button onClick={this.add}>add</button>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Live example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8ulzqe?file=index.js).

Answer (score 22):

**All data types**

`useState` returns a pair - an array with two elements. The first element is the current value and the second is a function that allows us to update it. If we update the current value, then no rendering is called. If we use a function, then the rendering is called.

```
const stateVariable = React.useState("value");

stateVariable[0]="newValue"; //update without rendering
stateVariable[1]("newValue");//update with rendering
```

**Object**

If a state variable is declared as an object, then we can change its first element. In this case, rendering is not called.

```
const [myVariable, setMyVariable] = React.useState({ key1: "value" });

myVariable.key1 = "newValue"; //update without rendering
setMyVariable({ key1:"newValue"}); //update with rendering
```

**Array**

If a state variable is declared as an array, then we can change its first element. In this case, rendering is not called.

```
const [myVariable, setMyVariable] = React.useState(["value"]);

myVariable[0] = "newValue"; //update without rendering
setMyVariable(["newValue"]); //update with rendering
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: Genius! Seems obvious now that you've shown how to do it. Thanks! :)

Comment: "If we update the current value, then no rendering is called. If we use a function, then the rendering is called", ok it works *today* but the problem is that I can't see the difference between `myVariable[0] = "newValue";` and `this.state.myVariable = "newValue";` which throws the following error by React: "Do not mutate state directly. Use setState() react/no-direct-mutation-state"

Comment: Example myVariable[0] = "newValue"; is for a function and example this.state.myVariable = "newValue"; is for a class.

Answer (score 15):

None of the answers work for TypeScript, so I'll add this. One method is to instead use the useRef hook and edit the value directly by accessing the 'current' property. See here:

`const [myState, setMyState] = useState<string>("");`

becomes

`let myState = useRef<string>("");`

and you can access it via:

`myState.current = "foobar";`

So far I'm not seeing any drawbacks. However, if this is to prevent a child component from updating, you should consider using the useMemo hook instead for readability. The useMemo hook is essentially a component that's given an explicit dependency array.

Comment: The drawback with using useRef in this case is, reading from `ref.current` during rendering could cause unpredictable behavior. This is one of the caveats listed in the react docs: https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useRef

Comment: Good point Abdul, probably the only way to use this pattern should be in useEffects--never directly in the logic of the functional component as I would expect that to conflict with the render lifecycle. https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 3):

It's as easy as using `this.state.stateName = value`. This will change the state without re-rendering, unlike using `this.setState({stateName:value})`, which will re-render. For example;

```
class Button extends React.Component {
    constructor( props ){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            message:"Hello World!"
        };
        this.method = this.method.bind(this);
    }
    method(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.state.message = "This message would be stored but not rendered";
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div >
                {this.state.message}
                <form onSubmit={this.method}> 
                    <button type="submit">change state</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Button />, document.getElementById('myDiv'));
```

Comment: yeah that will gt you a nice warning about direct state mutation: "Do not mutate state directly. Use setState()  react/no-direct-mutation-state"

Comment: In TypeScript attempting to mutate `this.state` doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a container to store the values, try `useRef`. Changing the value of `ref.current` doesn't lead to re-rendering.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [ loading,setLoading] = useState(false)

loading=true //does not rerender
setLoading(true) //will rerender
```

In functional component refer above code, for class use componentShouldUpdate lifecycle

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).