# React state: does changing state twice guarantees triggering render twice too?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

In React: Does changing state n times also triggering render n times too?

Is there any way to ignore some state changing based on the max browser fps rate?

I'm not sure using `useTransition`. It seem on experimental stage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to update react state without re rendering component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54066556/how-to-update-react-state-without-re-rendering-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend reading [this article](https://medium.com/swlh/react-state-batch-update-b1b61bd28cd2) about batch update if you mean by different state object changes. But basically, no. It doesn't guarantees triggering render n times following state change.

As for limiting it using browser fps rate - it's an interesting question. I guess it can be implemented using `requestAnimationFrame` the way libraries like [use-debounce](https://github.com/xnimorz/use-debounce) are implemented