# Why is my data not rendering appropriately?

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, rendering

I'm still struggling with React Natives rendering order. I'm fetching the API, then I filter this data and finally I'm manipulating the data. When I first load the app, it does not show the Data appropriately only when I'm saving within my code editor it shows up.

My simplified code:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [sumPost, setSumPost] = useState(0);
const [sumProd, setSumProd] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = db.collection("Dates").where("projektName", "==", Projektname).onSnapshot(snapshot => (
          setData(
            snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
            id: doc.id,
            data: doc.data(),
            })))
        ))
        return unsubscribe;
      }, [])

const produktionsFilter = data.filter( x => 
      x.data.jobtype == "Produktion"
    );

const postFilter = data.filter( x => 
      x.data.jobtype == "Postproduktion"
    );

const terminFilter = data.filter( x =>
      x.data.jobtype == "Termin"
    );

let i;

    const addPostProdTage = () => {
      const post = [];
      const prod = [];
      for(i=0; i < postFilter.length; i++){
        const p = postFilter[i].data.alleTage.length;
        post.push(p)
      }
      for(i=0; i < produktionsFilter.length; i++){
        const l = produktionsFilter[i].data.alleTage.length;
        prod.push(l)
      }
      setSumPost(post.reduce(function(a, b){
        return a + b;
      }, 0));
      setSumProd(prod.reduce(function(a, b){
        return a + b;
      }, 0));
    }

useEffect(() => {
      addPostProdTage();
    }, [])

return(
<View>
   <Text>{sumPost}</Text>
   <Text>{sumProd}</Text>
</View>
)
```

sumProd should be 18 and sumPost should be 3. Right now it is showing 0 on both, because both states are empty arrays initially. It needs to some sort refresh.

I'm sure, there are more efficient ways to code this, but I need help to understand, why my data is not showing appropriately when I first load the app, because I'm running into this problem over and over again.

Comment: I think you put wrong variables inside state, please put `sumPost` and `sumProd` inside state and then call the hook function ( might be `setSumPost` and `setSumProd` ) after you calculated them

Comment: Thank you! I now understand to not create local variables but instead use useStates.

Comment: If you want a re-render, you need to change the state using the hook function in your code.
I think you would optimize your code by using only one object which has both `sumPost` and `sumProd` properties, and just call the hook function after you finished the calculation to update both `sumPost` and `sumProd`, you might not need `useState`s for other variables.

Comment: @ArminGhoreishi Thank you for replying. I'm close to throwing my computer out of the window. I still can't get it to work. I created two states (sumProd and sumPost), I have a function, that goes through the API array and pushes specific values into a new array, so that I can calculate the sum of these specific values. And that sum needs to be displayed. It still is "0", the initial value and doesn't update... I updated the question, it would be very kind if you point out the beginner level mistakes that I'm making, so that I can avoid making these over and over again!

Comment: Look, the `data` is not ready yet when you are doing the filtering and calc, you are filtering an empty array I think, please make sure that the `data` is filled with data when you are calling `addPostProdTage` function. You might need to do the filtering and calculation process inside `onSnapshot ` callback.

Comment: I finally figured it out, your advise on filtering inside onSnapshot was one of the key components I needed. Also, I was able to simplify all the calculation to avoid a couple of steps. Thank you @ArminGhoreishi !

Comment: Glad to hear that, good luck @crypticalmindz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all the advise I got on here, so for future reference this is how I solved this:

I filtered the data inside snapshot:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const post = db
      .collection("Dates")
      .where("projektName", "==", Projektname)
      .where("jobtype", "==", "Postproduktion")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
        setPost(
          snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
            id: doc.id,
            data: doc.data(),
          }))
        )
      );
    return post;
  }, []);
```

I had unnecessary steps to do my calculation. I could simplify this into a single function:

```
const revData = () => {
    setSumPost(
      post.reduce(function (prev, cur) {
        return prev + cur.data.alleTage.length;
      }, 0)
    );
  };
```

And finally, I had a useEffect to call that function after the data has been fetched using the dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
    revData();
  }, [post]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating local variables that go out of scope. You would be able to catch this error if you were using typescript instead of javascript.

You want to instead create state objects like this:

```
  const [sumPost, setSumPost] = useState(0)
  const [sumProd, setSumProd] = useState(0);
```

And then set the values of those objects as shown:

```
    setSumPost(postproduktionsTage.reduce(function(a, b){
      return a + b;
    }, 0));

    setSumProd(produktionsTage.reduce(function(a, b){
      return a + b;
    }, 0));
```

And then you can use it as you desire:

```
return(
<View>
   <Text>{sumPost}</Text>
   <Text>{sumProd}</Text>
</View>
)
```

Comment: That makes sense! I updated the code in my initial question, because now, I guess due to both setStates, I have too many re-renders, is that right? How can I avoid that mistake, so I understand? Thank you for your help!

Comment: There’s many ways of doing that, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62320075/11104068

Comment: ""State" is read-only". I'm slowly giving up... I think I haven't understood the whole concept of rendering order how to control it. Can I optimize something in my code I posted in the question to solve this? I would appreciate your help!

Comment: I am not sure what you're talking about. Here, take a look at this example I created for you: https://snack.expo.dev/@saamerm/stackoverflow-answer
It's a simplified version of your code so you can understand what's going on

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to create that example! I posted a sort of summary answer for future reference!

Comment: I’m glad you figured out the answer. Don’t forget to mark it as the answer :)